# TypeScript console.log doesn't work

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying out TypeScript on Node.js. 
I have installed it using 
`npm install typescript`

When just run `tsc`:

`:~$ tsc
Version 1.0.1.0
Syntax:   tsc [options] [file ..]`

So, I am trying to run simple code:
`console.log('test');`
which is not outputing nothing.

How can I output anyting in console from typescript running on node.js?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

tsc is a compiler not a repl.

You need to write your typescript , compile it with tsc then execute it with nodejs.

Comment: Right, I see that now. But I can write something like `tsc test.ts | node test.js` and have it executed immediately. Thanks.

Comment: @AndrijaCacanovic If you are using Bash you would only want to invoke node if the tsc command was successful:

`tsc test.ts && node test.js`

Comment: The answer below works, by using **ts-node** NPM package. I just tried it and it's the correct answer.

Answer (score 11):

With **ts-node**, which is a TypeScript execution environment, you can now execute TypeScript with node as you expected from the tsc compiler.

After installing ts-node you can run your example directly as

```
ts-node -e 'console.log("test")'
```

or you can run a TypeScript file as:

```
ts-node script.ts
```

Please find further details on the [ts-node npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node)

Comment: Use: ts-node -e 'console.log("test")' . Otherwise the nested single quotes confuse the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is not necessary but is very simple what you ask.

after write

> console.log('test');
> Save this by example as test.ts

then run the command tsc test.ts (this will compile your code to JS) you will see a new file created by tsc with the name test.js

Now you can run your test by typing: node test.js

I hope it works for you

Answer (score 1):

You need to install this dev depending

```
npm i -D @types/node
```